# Automate Wordpress Database Upgrade

Tags: database, automatic-updates

I've set up auto-updates on my Wordpresses by adding

```
/* Updates */
define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true);
```

in the `wp-config.php` file.

Once Wordpress releases a new version, when I try to reach the wp-admin, I get this screen [image: screen] 
that complains me about a db upgrade required. After hitting the button, the db is upgraded and I get this screen [image: screen] 
and all restart to work.

How can I remove and automate this annoying request from Wordpress?
Is there some code to put in the `wp-config.php` file?
A standard user of my Wordpresses is scared by seeing these screens.
As I done with Major Releases, can I automate this db upgrade?

Comment: Based on what I can tell auto-update-core will automatically update database versions for you as well. All I can think is that this process failed for you. You might check your PHP error logs around the time you suspect you received the upgrade and submit a bug via Trac.

Answer (score 2):

So are you going to automate your backup as well to be triggered before the DB upgrade starts?

While the question has merit especially in a multisite context (in which the scenario is a little different) I am not sure that it is smart thing to do. That message could have said "this is your last chance to perform a backup of the DB, click the button only after you have done it".

While it has been a long time since wordpress had a major risky DB change, this may happen again. Are you sure that you want your site to fail without you immediately knowing about that? The 30 seconds you waste every 4 moths is a small price to pay for the peace of mind, especially if those are site you are paid to maintain.

Comment: I have all my sites backed-up once a day (files and db), and I keep these backup for 6 months in a storage device.
I need to remove this prompt from Wordpress since I have auto-update and maybe my customers access the backend before me (and I don't want to annoy them, even more if they are paying me to develop, create, modify and maintain their sites).

Comment: As I said the question has merit. I would say that the problem starts with you having automatic updates enabled at all. The problem with backups is never the backup itself but always the restore. If it takes you a week to identify a failure (lets say yaost SEO had failed, something you will not notice immediately), how do you restore without losing new content that was added in that week?

Comment: It's an hard subject what are you saying. Versioning db tables is not a trivial problem and I'd like to discuss with you about this, perhaps in a new question. But this is detached from my original question. So suppose I have a system that can save, catalog and restore efficently a wordpress db.

Comment: What's the point of being able to auto update core if it doesn't autoupdate the database with it. The question is very valid, and the core team have already decided it's something that should be able to be done.